# Servlet 3 issues with @WebFilter and @WebServlet deployment

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I am trying to migrate my existing servlets and filters defined in `web.xml` file to `@WebServlet` and `@WebFilter` annotations on Glassfish V3 server.

Currently `web.xml` defined 12 servlets and 6 filters .
Tried removing one servlet from `web.xml` file and added `@WebServlet` annotation to Java servlet file .

But having difficulty in accessing the servlet when ever my JSP trying to access Servlet Glassfish complains "Service Not Available".

basically Servlet and filter defined using annotations never identified by Glassfish Server 3.

Is this existing bug that annotations can not be used along with `web.xml` file ?
Do we have any workaround.

I referred following [Sun documentation](https://glassfish-samples.dev.java.net/source/browse/*checkout*/glassfish-samples/ws/javaee6//web/servlet/annotation-war/docs/index.html) to migrate web.xml to servlet 3 annotations

Comment: Like anything in Java, annotations are case sensitive. Thus, it should really have been `@WebServlet` and `@WebFilter`. Although that would have produced completely different and obvious errors, please keep this in mind as well when describing a problem, just to avoid red herrings.

Comment: Sorry for the typo BalusC , its @WebFilter and @WebServlet

Comment: can you show us the relevant portion of web.xml and the relevant portion of the servlet's java code?

Answer (score 3):

You've got to get your web.xml correct, below is the beginning of the web.xml you should use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    metadata-complete="false" 
    version="3.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a 2.5 version declaration and the @WebServlet annotation was ignored, this answer solved the problem.