# java, tomcat: what is the meaning of the id attribute in the tag web-app in web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat7

What is the meaning of web.xml **id** attribute of the **web-app** tag?

Eclipse generated it as **id="WebApp_ID"**. I was using version the Servlet specification version 2.5, I switched to using 3.0, with the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095024/servlet-3-issues-with-webfilter-and-webservlet-deployment/3386526#answers) that doesn't include that id.

Is it really necessary? What is the value supposed to be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The newer versions of the servlet spec use .xsd files with no further information on the id attribute, but if you go back to the older versions with .dtd, such as [web_app_2_2.dtd](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd), you find:

> The ID mechanism is to allow tools to
>   easily make tool-specific references
>   to the elements of the deployment
>   descriptor. This allows tools that
>   produce additional deployment
>   information (i.e information beyond
>   the standard deployment descriptor
>   information) to store the non-standard
>   information in a separate file, and
>   easily refer from these tools-specific
>   files to the information in the
>   standard web-app deployment
>   descriptor.

For example, WebSphere Application Server used the id mechanism in its old bnd and ext files:

```
web.xml:
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" ...

ibm-web-app-bnd.xmi:
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding ...
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
```

(Thankfully, this is tool-friendly-but-developer-annoying use of id attributes is no longer necessary with the newer .xml file format for ibm-web-bnd/ext, but I digress.)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not needed (per the [DTD](http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd) as well). You can comment it out and see if that works, I am quite positive the app will load up just fine.